# C# EdiFabric: Extra UNT Message Trailer Segment

Tags: c#, edi

I'm exporting an X12 EDI 835, but when I generate the .txt file an extra segment is appearing. It seems to be an EDIFACT EDI UNT segment, which shouldn't appear since this is an X12 format and uses an SE segment for listing segment counts. Here's an example:

`UNT*106*0001~`

Code used to generate the 835:

```
    var ediInterchange = new X12Interchange(interchangeHeader);
    var groupHeader = CreateGs();
    var ediGroup = new X12Group<M_835>(groupHeader);
    var m835 = Create835Message();

    ediInterchange.AddItem(ediGroup);
    ediGroup.AddItem(m835);

    var defaultSeparators = Separators.DefaultX12();
    var newSeparators = new Separators(defaultSeparators.Segment,
                    ':',
                    defaultSeparators.DataElement,
                    defaultSeparators.RepetitionDataElement,
                    null);

    var ediSegments = ediInterchange.GenerateEdi(newSeparators);
    var ediSegmentArray = ediSegments as string[] ?? ediSegments.ToArray();
    var edi = ediSegmentArray.Aggregate("", (current, segment) => current + segment + Environment.NewLine);

    var errors = Validation(m835);
```

Comment: have you at least put breakpoints in the code and evaluated / checked the value of your variables in the debugger?

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, there is no UNT segment within the 835 object. When the library generates edi segments using the passed in 835 message, it also creates a UNT segment. I'm not sure what's causing the UNT segment to be created; I would expect an SE segment instead.

Comment: Hi @BenSwanson , did you menage this problem? Can you provide any resolution?

Comment: @Skamielina Yes, I added a step after creating the file to look for and remove extra segments if they exist. Not ideal, but it works for me.